# Visual Studio 2017 javascript syntax highlight

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I use Visual Studio 2017 (v.15.9) to code C# ASP.NET websites with a lot of **javascript** for the front-end.

Is there a way to **customize the syntax highlight colors** of JavaScript code blocks?

I need for both .js files, and also for the code block I insert directly in some html/aspx file, the code inside the `<script>` tag

Comment: May be you can find VS addon you need here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Format&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs15&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: @bestinamir I've searched a lot but I haven't found anything for javascript, but it seems so strange I'm the only one with this issue

Comment: New and revamped text editor (VS2019) is coming out very soon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-preview-relnotes#editor

Comment: Similar problem? Or may be post your question here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32425/javascript-syntax-highlighting-it-not-working.html

Comment: You can edit all colors under Menu > Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors, or is that not what the question is about?

Comment: @MrLister Yes I know, but not for javascript like it's styled in VS Code. I've tried also some extension, SemanticColorizer i.e., but they are not able to work on the javascript code, specially when this is embedded inside an html, or aspx page.

Comment: Oh... I can't compare VS Code and VS 2017, but I can edit the colors as above in VS 2017 and it does work the same way for .js files and <script> blocks in .aspx files, so I'm not sure what more you need.

Comment: @MrLister what elements have you changed for changing the js code style?

Comment: comment, identifier etc. Why don't you specify what you want to do exactly.